# Remove string between two characters using no regex Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, replace, text-files

I'm trying to remove a sentence from a text file that I'm uploading through an Input file. I need to remove all sentences that are between '/*' and '*/' so comments line basically. Also all the single line comments such as '//' but I took care of it already. For that I'm not allowed to use any regex or replace function. Is there anyone who can help me on that ? Thanks

```
class Inpute extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fileName: '',
      fileContent: ''
    };
  }

  handleFile = e =>{
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file);
    reader.onload = () => {
      this.setState({fileName: file.name, fileContent: reader.result});
      if(reader.result.includes('//')){
        var newText = reader.result
        newText = newText
                .split('\n')
                .filter(x => !x.includes('\/\/'))
                .join('\n')

        this.setState({fileName: file.name, fileContent: newText})
      }
    }
    reader.onerror = () =>{
      console.log('File Error : ', reader.error)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you post an example input

Comment: `.filter(x => !x.includes('/*') && !x.includes('*/'))`

Comment: The code you have will remove the entire line if it has a comment on it. For instance, a line like `if (x === y) { // check if x equals y` will remove the `if` statement too. I don't know whether that matters or not. If not, then you just need to check if the line contains two `/` characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split string by `/`. Parts that you need to delete are all in odd indexes so filter them out and join this array back into string.

```js
const string = 'asdasada a/kkkkkkkk/a sdad asda s/xxxxx/s dasd';

const arr = string.split('/').filter((_, index) => index%2 === 0);

console.log(arr.join(''));
```

## UPDATE

I have changed my example to filter only comments

```js
const line = 'asdasada a/*kkkkkkkk*/a sdad asda s/*xxxxxs dasd x asda sd\n' +
    'asdas */das a// asdasda\n' +
    'x/*bbbbb*/c ad';
let prevPart = null;
let haveDoubleSlashes = false;

const cleaned = line.split('/').map(part => {

    // single line comments
    if (haveDoubleSlashes || part === '') {
        haveDoubleSlashes = true;

        if (part.includes('\n')) {
            part = '\n' + part.split('\n')[1];
            haveDoubleSlashes = false;
        } else {
            part = null;
        }

        return part;
    }

    /* multiline comments */
    if (part.startsWith('*') && part.endsWith('*')) {
        prevPart = null;
        return null;
    }

    if (prevPart !== null) {
        part = '/' + part;
    }

    prevPart = part;

    return part;
}).filter(part => part !== null).join('');

console.log(cleaned);
```

Comment: Thanks it's exactly what I needed ! u saved me !

Comment: @MikeFisher keep in mind that this script will not work on multiline comments. This you have to figure out yourself.

Comment: @PeterSeliger yeah. I said that already.

Comment: @ciekals11 ... thanks for the last update ... it perfectly passes the multiline "Lorem ipsum" test of my approach. My initial voting got reestablished.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Well. It passed your test but is not ideal. If in multiline comment (`/**/`) is another single line comment (`//`) script will only remove this single line and multiline will remain. I don't have enough motivation for fixing it.

Comment: @ciekals11 ... Thanks for noticing. I updated `sampleData` of my answer's example code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If all you care about is if the line contains two solidus characters (`/`), just filter on that:

```js
const sample = `blah blah // blah blah\nblah blah /blah blah/ blah\nblah blah blah`;
const lines = sample.split('\n');
const good = lines.filter(x => 
  // [...x] makes the line an array of characters
  // reduce runs for each character, aggregating the result. 
  // agg is the aggregation, cur is the current character
  // Here it's just counting the number of /s and returning false if there are
  // fewer than two
  [...x].reduce((agg, cur) => agg = cur === '/' ? agg + 1 : agg, 0) < 2
  
);
console.log(good.join('\n'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function stripMultilineComments(str) {
  let posOpen;
  let posClose;

  while ((posOpen = str.indexOf('/*')) !== -1) {

    posClose = Math.max(
      0, str.indexOf('*/', (posOpen + 2))
    ) || (str.length - 2);

    str = [
      str.substring(0, posOpen),
      str.substring(posClose + 2),
    ].join('');
  }
  return str;
}
function stripSingleLineComment(str) {
  let idx;
  if (
    (str.trim() !== '') &&
    ((idx = str.indexOf('//')) !== -1)
  ) {
    str = str.substring(0, idx);
  }
  return str;
}

function stripComments(value) {
  return stripMultilineComments(
    String(value)
  )
  .split('\n')
  .map(stripSingleLineComment)
  .join('\n');
}
const sampleData = `
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet/*, consectetur adipiscing elit,
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt*/ ut labore et dolore
  magna aliqua. // Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris/*nisi ut 
  aliquip //ex ea commodo consequat*/. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit// in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
  eu fugiat nulla pariatur.// Excepteur sint occaecat
  /*cupidatat non //proident, */sunt in culpa qui officia
  deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
`;

console.log(
  stripComments(sampleData)
);
console.log(
  stripComments(sampleData) === `
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ut labore et dolore
  magna aliqua. 
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit
  eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  sunt in culpa qui officia
  deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```